# PHP division resulting in zero

Tags: php, integer-division

I am trying to do some division in my PHP program and for some reason the result is zero when it should not be.
Below is my code:

```
print("Historic Total: '$histoicTotal' Valid weeks: '$numValidWeeks'");

$historicAvg = $historicTotal/$numValidWeeks;

print(($historicTotal)/($numValidWeeks));
print(30/1);

$totalAvg = (($historicAvg + $avg)/2);
print("Havg = '$historicAvg' + Avg '$avg' "); 
print($totalAvg);
```

The output is `Historic Total: '30' Valid weeks: '1'030Havg = '0' + Avg '' 0`

Comment: Well your `$avg` variable is clearly empty.

Answer (score 2):

There is a typo: `$histoicTotal` is missing "r" in the middle. Compare to variable name on the second line: `$historicTotal`.